# Converting carpeted stairs to hardwood stairs

Tags: stairs, carpet, hardwood

[image][image]We removed the carpet from our stairs expecting to find plywood stair treads however, that is not what we found. instead, they did three 2x4s. It’s all extremely uneven and I’m not really sure what to do now. My original plan was to just put the new hardwood treads on top of the plywood treads but now I don’t think that I can do that. I can’t find any tips or videos online where people have used two by fours to build stairs. I’m new to this and it won’t let me post a photo.

Comment: have a pic for us to see it

Comment: I figured out how to add one.

Comment: Thank you. You will need plywood on that for the hardwood.

Comment: Do I need to sand down the two by fours to put the plywood down? And then the hardwood on top?

Comment: Adding plywood then the hardwood treads could make the rise too high.  How uneven is  "Uneven" ?   You may be able to attach your hardwood right over the current 2x s if your treads are one piece.  It may require a shim or 2.

Comment: The treads I bought are all one piece. now that I’ve been looking at them I feel like they’re maybe just slightly uneven. I will add another photo from a different angle.

Comment: Are these stairs solidly built--no movement when force is applied? It looks like the middle plank is protruding above the other two. Is that correct? How many steps are there and what is the rise and run of each step? If you are going to plane down protuuding planks, then you should first set the nail heads to below where you would plane to or you would damage the planer blade as it contacted the nail heads.

Comment: What is the flooring at the top of the stairs?

Answer (score 1):

A planer (hand or powered) and a sharp wood chisel will easily level those 2x4s for direct mounting of the new treads. I would use construction glue in addition to fasteners, for squeak prevention.

You will need to consider max rise (from top of finished lower floor to top of first finished tread; from top of each finished tread to top of the next finished tread; and from top of the highest finished tread to the level of the finished landing/floor surface) of 7 3/4" (also, max of 3/8" difference in tread height between any 2 treads). You shouldn't need plywood and in fact, adding plywood will make the problem of incorrect rise even worse.